# Ant is not compiling *.properties files

Tags: java, ant, build

I'm new to Ant and am having some issues compiling my project.  I have several `.properties` files in my project `src/`.  I'm compiling my project to a `.WAR` via my `build.xml` (posted below).  When deploying, I see several `FileNotFound` exceptions and even after unpacking the `.WAR` file, I see that the `*.properties` files are not present in my final distribution. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="APP" default="war">

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac destdir="build/classes" includeantruntime="false" debug="true" srcdir="src">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="dist/APP.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" duplicate="preserve">
        <fileset dir="WebContent" />
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <classes dir="build/classes" />
    </war>
</target>
```

Comment: Add an additional `classes` element for the static files, like, `<classes dir="src" includes="*.properties"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply did not include those properties files when calling the `war` task. You should explicitly include them (I used a `zipfileset` to add a prefix so that they are placed in the right path):

```
<war destfile="dist/APP.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" duplicate="preserve">
    <fileset dir="WebContent" />
    <zipfileset dir="src"
          prefix="WEB-INF/classes">
          <include name="**/*.properties"/>
    </zipfileset>
    <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
</war>
```

Or as proposed by srkavin in the comments (but with some modification to include files in subdirectories):

```
<war destfile="dist/APP.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml" duplicate="preserve">
    <fileset dir="WebContent" />
    <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
    <classes dir="src" includes="**/*.properties"/>
</war>
```

Comment: This seems to make sense; unfortunately, even after applying this change, the .properties files are still not a part of the final distro.  Is there anything else that might be blocking the functionality of this implementation?

Comment: I see that it's including it, but not in the `classes/` directory where it needs to be.

Comment: @Sean Updated. Admittedly though, the proposed solution by srkavin is better.